# ¿Cómo saber si un nombre aparece en dos columnas de la misma tabla?

Tags: sql

Tengo una tabla en la que tengo una columna que se llama `ACTORES` y otra que se llama `PRODUCTOR`. Necesito que primero me muestre el número de veces que aparece cada nombre y, además de eso, qué nombres aparecen también tanto en actor como en productor.

Estas dos cosas las sé hacer por separado perfectamente, ya que lo primero es así:

```
SELECT ACTOR, COUNT(ACTOR) "Número de peliculas"
FROM MOVIES
GROUP BY ACTOR
HAVING COUNT(ACTOR)>0;
```

Y lo segundo así:

```
SELECT ACTOR
FROM MOVIES
INTERSECT
SELECT PRODUCTOR
FROM MOVIES;
```

Pero no encuentro la forma de que haga las dos cosas a la vez.

Había pensado en hacer lo primero pero con una tercera columna en la que salga `SÍ` o `NO` dependiendo de si aparece en la columna de `PRODUCTOR`, pero no sé cómo hacerlo. ¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT
  ACTOR,
  COUNT(ACTOR) "Número de peliculas",
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM MOVIES m2
    WHERE m2.ACTOR = m2.PRODUCTOR
      AND m2.ACTOR = m.ACTOR
  ) "Número de producciones"
FROM MOVIES m
GROUP BY ACTOR
HAVING COUNT(ACTOR) > 0
```

Por cada registro agrupado hago una subconsulta preguntando cuántas veces aparece ese actor también como productor.

Puedes ver el código funcionando en línea aquí:

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kYepqTsKMYqw9ukP6LvP5B/0

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!